# how to select the strings between the textbox.contain() code?

Tags: vb.net, string, vb.net-2010, delimiter

What I want to do actually is I want to find a strings in a textbox. My idea is using IF to find the current string for example;

If Textbox1.Contain("<") AndAlso Textbox1.Contain(">") Then
'I want to select the strings between the < and > to do MySQL command.
End If

How can I do that? Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution without messing with RegEx could be this (it really depends on your needs):

```
<HideModuleName>
Public Module StringExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function GetFirstStringBetween(ByVal sender As String,
                                          ByVal delimiterA As String,
                                          ByVal delimiterB As String) As String

        If sender.Contains(delimiterA) AndAlso sender.Contains(delimiterB) Then

            Dim rightPart As String = sender.Substring(sender.IndexOf(delimiterA) + 1)

            If rightPart.Contains(delimiterB) Then
                Return rightPart.Substring(0, sender.IndexOf(delimiterB) - 1)
            End If

        End If

        Return sender

    End Function

End Module
```

Usage:

```
Dim str As String = "<Hello World> <Bye World>"
Dim result As String = str.GetFirstStringBetween("<", ">")

Console.WriteLine(result)
```

Comment: But I got error said 'GetFirstStringBetween' is not a member of 'String'. What was that error? Sorry actually im also quite new in vb :D

Comment: @Johns Yong Yes, my mistake, I forgot to assign the <Extension> attribute to the extension method, see the updated code.

Comment: I see this solution is helpful to me. Thank you for your effort. God bless you :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with VB. But may be you want to try using regular expression. It's pretty useful for searching and extracting.
Something like below should work.

```
Dim strBetween As String
strBetween = Regex.Match(TextBox1.text, "<(.*?)>").Value
```

Or you can do as below example:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("<(.*?)>")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(TextBox1.text)
    If match.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Please let me know if it work.

Comment: Sorry to ask.. But if you dont mind to tell me, what is Regex?

Comment: I got error when using Regex. The error is 'Property access must assign to the property or use its value.

Comment: Sorry, my example code is not a completed code. The error you got that because Value is property, so may be you have to assign it to other variable or use it. I edited the answer.

Comment: I am really sorry but I cant get your solution, but anyway, thank you very very much for your effort :D God bless you

Comment: Maybe this could be useful on another part of my task :D

Comment: You welcome. Just keep in mind that when search and extract text, regular expression work like a charm. You can start learning regex (regular expression) from here http://regexone.com/.